# How do I remove just the 2xl breakpoint in Tailwind 2?

Tags: media-queries, responsive, tailwind-css

I have upgraded to tailwind 2 which has a new `2xl` breakpoint. This causes any element with a `container` class to become wider than it used to.

How can I remove just the `2xl` breakpoint while keeping all the other default breakpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the [breakpoints documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints#extending-the-default-breakpoints) explins how to override existing breakpoints or add new ones, it does not explain how to remove a single breakpoint.

In your `tailwind.config.js` file enter the following.

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(defaultTheme.screens).filter(([key, value]) => key !== '2xl')
    )
  }
}
```

This works by importing the `defaultTheme`, converting its `screens` object to key/value "entries", filtering those entires by key to exclude `2xl`, then recombining the result of the filter back into an object using `fromEntires()`.

Optionally, if you only want to keep certain breakpoints, you can invert the filter.

```js
    screens: Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(defaultTheme.screens).filter(([key, value]) => ['sm', 'xl'].includes(key))
    )
```

The above would only keep the `sm` and `xl` breakpoints.

Comment: Usually, you only have 3/4 breakpoints. So, writing all of them -1 is not so time consuming neither. ^^

Comment: @kissu sure, but then you're duplicating values that could change.

Comment: Only writing 3 values in your tailwind config file rather than 4 no?

Comment: @kissu I'd rather cherry pick the defaults than re-enter their values. That way updates to defaultTheme pass through.